# Issue updating a GridView row with DropDownList and TextBox controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am encountering an error while attempting to update a row in a GridView control using DropDownList and TextBox controls. The GridView contains a TemplateField with a DropDownList control for the "Status" column and an EditItemTemplate with TextBox controls for other columns. The DropDownList is populated with status options, and when I try to update a row, I receive the following error message:

"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID statusa', table 'Karlo_Miskovic.dbo.Narudžba'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails."

I have reviewed my code and made sure that the DropDownList control has a selected value, and the TextBox controls have the appropriate values. However, the error still persists. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue.

Here is the relevant code snippet:
.asxp:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[Status]") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Neobrađeno" Value="Neobrađeno"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="U obradi" Value="U obradi"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Završeno" Value="Završeno"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Status]") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

.vb:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    ' Retrieve the new values entered by the user
    Dim orderID As Integer = Integer.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
    Dim deliveryDate As Date = Date.Parse(CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtDatumIsporuke"), TextBox).Text)
    Dim status As String = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlStatus"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
    ' Other variable assignments...

    ' Rest of the code...

End Sub
```

I have also ensured that the database column 'ID statusa' is not set to allow null values. Despite these measures, the error persists. Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

add this code and try again

```
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               //bind your gridview
                BindGridView1();
            }
```

in vb

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    'bind your gridview
    BindGridView1()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your project settings, you could also use

```
Dim ddlStatus As DropDownList = 
   GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlStatus")

ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Value -- gets value
ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text -- gets text
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked.
Instead of:

```
Dim status As String = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlStatus"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
```

I did this:

```
Dim ddlStatus As DropDownList = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlStatus"), DropDownList)
ddlStatus.SelectedValue
```